# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'SPAN_ID' of undefined in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined

I have a response where I am getting `datalist` as `[]` and its error is coming as

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'SPAN_ID' of undefined

Below is the code

```js
function GETSPANINFO(PARAM) {
    try {
        showLoading();
        $(spandetailsdiv).hide();
        var SpanType = $(spantypeid + ' option:selected').val().toUpperCase();
        var SPANID = "";
        var NE_LEG = 0;
        var PL_LEG = 0;
        Values = PARAM;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: AppConfig.PrefixURL + "App/GetSPANInfo",
            data: JSON.stringify(Values),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            success: function (response) {
                hideLoading();
                var datalist = JSON.parse(response);

                //$.each(datalist.Table, function (index, element) {
                //    spanid = element.SPAN_ID;
                //    NE_LEG = element.NE_LENGTH;
                //});
                //printRouteHistory(response, NE_LEG);
                if (SpanType == 'FTTX') {
                    $('#dvCTRouteAcceptedPendingFTTX').hide();
                    spanid = datalist[0].SPAN_ID;
                    NE_LEG = parseFloat(datalist[0].NE_LENGTH).toFixed(3);
                    //var COM_LEG = parseFloat(datalist[0].COMM).toFixed(3);
                    var UG_LEG = parseFloat(datalist[0].UGLEG).toFixed(3);
                    var AR_LEG = parseFloat(datalist[0].ARLEG).toFixed(3);
                    var MDU_LEG = parseFloat(datalist[0].MDULEG).toFixed(3);
                    fn = true;
                    $(spandetailsdiv + ' div.header h2').html(spanid);
                    $('#spnfsaid').html(spanid);
                    // $(spnfsaid).html(spanid);    
                    $('#spnfsalength').html(NE_LEG);

                    // $(pendingSpanLen).html(NE_LEG);
                    $('#UGLEG_txt').val(UG_LEG);
                    $('#ARLEG_txt').val(AR_LEG);
                    //$('#MDU_txt').val(MDU_LEG);
                    $('#MDULEG_txt').val(MDU_LEG);
                   $('#ctfsadatepicker').val(datalist[0].HOTODATE);
                  // $('#ctfsadatepickerParfttx').val(datalist[0].HOTODATE); 

                   $('#ddlmissingabd1').show();

                } else {

                    $('#dvConstructionDetails').show();
                    $('#dvConstructionDetails_fttx').hide();
                    $('#dvFiberEngDetails_fttx').hide();          
                   // $('#btnSubmitCT').show();

                    $('#ddlmissingabd1').hide();

                    spanid = datalist[0].SPAN_ID || 0;   // here is the error
                    NE_LEG = datalist[0].NE_LENGTH || 0;  

                    fn = true;
                    $(spandetailsdiv + ' div.header h2').html(spanid);
                    $(spnLinkId).html(spanid);
                    $(spnspanlength).html(NE_LEG);
                    $(pendingSpanLen).html(NE_LEG);
                    //$('#dvConstructionDetails').show();
                }
            },
            error: function (response) {
                hideLoading();
                AppLog.getLogger('error', response.toString());
            },

            complete: function () {
                $(spandetailsdiv).show();
                $('#dvConstructionPendingDetails').hide();
                $('#dvConstuctionRejectDetails').hide();
                $('#PendingForm_FTTx').hide();
                $('#btnPendingSubmitCT').show();

                if (SpanType == 'FTTX') {
                    $('#dvConstructionDetails').hide();
                    $('#dvConstructionDetails_fttx').show(); 
                    $('#dvConstructionPendingDetails_FTTx').hide();                      
                    $('#dvFiberEngDetails_fttx').hide();                                                //ashwini 
                    $('#btnSubmitCTfttx').show();                   
                    
                    //ashwini
                } else {
                    $('#dvConstructionDetails').show();
                    $('#dvConstructionDetails_fttx').hide();
                    $('#dvFiberEngDetails_fttx').hide();           
                    $('#PendingForm_FTTx').hide();
                    $('#btnSubmitCT').show();
                    $('#btnPendingSubmitCT').show();
                    $('#btnPendingParSubmitCT').hide();
                    //zoomToSpan(PARAM.SPANID + "|" + PARAM.SPANTYPE + "|" + PARAM.MZONE);
                    //routeInfoCallCTNew(PARAM.SPANID + "|" + PARAM.SPANTYPE + "|" + PARAM.MZONE + "|" + NE_LEG);
                }
                
                zoomToSpan(PARAM.SPANID + "|" + PARAM.SPANTYPE + "|" + PARAM.MZONE);
                routeInfoCallCTNew(PARAM.SPANID + "|" + PARAM.SPANTYPE + "|" + PARAM.MZONE + "|" + NE_LEG);
               
            }
        });
    } catch (e) {
        hideLoading();
        AppLog.getLogger('error', e.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: When you use `dataType: 'json'`, jQuery will call `JSON.parse()` automatically. You shouldn't call it yourself.

Comment: Change to `success: function(datalist)` and get rid of `var datalist = JSON.parse(response);`

Comment: @Barmar: after changing as u said, rest no need to change ?

Comment: Maybe. You might need to check that `datalist` is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, consider parsing only once the http response

```
success: function (datalist) {
                hideLoading();
                // use datalist directly
                ...
}
```

As indicated by the error, `datalist[0]` can be empty. So you can first try to see if the data exist before accessing the property SPAN_ID.

```
if(datalist[0]) {// do the processing}
```

Depending of the browser you are using, you can consider the optional chaining ( you would need to consider the compatibility of browser since it is a new feature of ES2020)

```
spanid = datalist[0]?.SPAN_ID
```

In this case spanid will be undefined if the data is not available. To set a default value, you can consider using the nullish coalescing operator `??`

Comment: If he's setting `datalist` incorrectly, this will stop the error but not make it work correctly.

Comment: The error is about reading a value from undefined. I don't see why datalist might be set incorrectly. It is true that it is pointless calling json.parse as you indicated in the comments of the question, but that does not make the assignment of datalist incorrect.

Comment: If it's parsing something that isn't JSON because it has already been parsed, `datalist` will not be set correctly.

Comment: i guess this would be more convenient `if(datalist[0]) {// do the processing}`